# Problems with numpy and ehtim

Tags: python, numpy

When I run my script, which worked fine yesterday. I now get the error messages:

C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ehtim\io\oifits.py:71: FutureWarning: In the future `np.bool` will be defined as the corresponding NumPy scalar.
from numpy import double, bool, ma
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\chri\BA-Proj\astroray_io.py", line 1, in 
import ehtim
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ehtim_*init*_.py", line 18, in 
from ehtim.imaging.imager_utils import imager_func
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ehtim\imaging\imager_utils.py", line 32, in 
import ehtim.image as image
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ehtim\image.py", line 47, in 
import ehtim.io.save
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ehtim\io_*init*_.py", line 9, in 
from . import load
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ehtim\io\load.py", line 35, in 
import ehtim.obsdata
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ehtim\obsdata.py", line 45, in 
import ehtim.io.save
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ehtim\io\save.py", line 31, in 
import ehtim.io.writeoifits
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ehtim\io\writeoifits.py", line 10, in 
import ehtim.io.oifits
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ehtim\io\oifits.py", line 71, in 
from numpy import double, bool, ma
ImportError: cannot import name 'bool' from 'numpy' (C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py)

How do I fix this?

I've tried to reinstall and check versions on the mentioned modules but everything seems to be in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to downgrade from the latest numpy version, which is causing the issue. So if you do:

```
pip install numpy==1.23.3
```

then it should work for you.

See also the discussion [here](https://github.com/achael/eht-imaging/issues/165) - this issue has been fixed, but the latest version has not been released on PyPI yet.